# How to customize file upload directory in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, filesystems

I am using Spring Boot to upload files. Currently, all the uploaded files are stored in a "upload dir" directory. Like this:

```
public static String ROOT = "upload-dir";
```

The upload method looks like this (ROOT is where the file will be stored):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) { 
        try { 
            // Java NIO to copy the input stream to a local file
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), Paths.get(ROOT, file.getOriginalFilename()));
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
        } catch (IOException|RuntimeException e) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Failued to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " => " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because it was empty");
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

How do I change ROOT so that it asks the user for a specific a temporary location instead of loading up the file system of the application?

Comment: I didn't get your question totally but if you want to change the *Intermediate Locations of Uploaded Files*, then set the `multipart.location` in your `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Change the ***ROOT*** to any path u want,like 'C:/myphoto'

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.16.RELEASE.

Configuration for application.yml:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      location: d:/root
```